# Usage of steps in antd v4 and v5

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm current using antd-v4 might upgrade to antd v5 sometime later, I need help in getting to know whether the following code will work fine with antd v5.

Since in antd-v4 it is mentioned that step will be removed in antd-v5 (Image attached) , but it seems to be working fine.

[image: Antd-v4 deprecation warning]

I need to use Step like the code below, since I have lots of conditions to work on like icon changing dynamically , showing error dynamically , need to save clicked object etc.. which is very difficult in latest version with just items = {items} and modifying inside array of objects

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shadow-tp5fw5?file=/src/Stepper.js

```
import { Steps } from "antd";

const Stepper = () => {
  const { Step } = Steps;
  const steppers = [
    {
      title: "Q1"
    },
    {
      title: "Q2"
    },
    {
      title: "Q3"
    },
    {
      title: "Q4"
    },
    {
      title: "Q5"
    },
    {
      title: "Q6"
    }
  ];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Steps
        current={current}
        onChange={(menuKey) => setCurrent(menuKey)}
        labelPlacement="vertical"
      >
        {steppers?.map((data) => {
          return <Step key={data.title} title={data.title} />;
        })}
      </Steps>
    </>
  );
};

export default Stepper;
```

Comment: You can still achieve everything with the new Steps component. You can store the items in a state and let's say you want to change the icon or the status of particular steps, just update the state. Please follow the [Steps API](https://ant.design/components/steps#api) for all available options.