# Dynamic icons in Steps antd v5

Tags: reactjs, antd

With the below code, I'm using a basic stepper, I need help in giving icons to each step, like if the step is finished it is changing as tick icon now,  in that place I need to give another icon and same for error, if error is in that step I need to give an icon.
It could be possible in antd v4 where we wrote like below [Usage of steps in antd v4 and v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76849312/usage-of-steps-in-antd-v4-and-v5) . Need some ideas in antd-v5

Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-5-8-2-forked-mpcgyt?file=/demo.tsx

```
import "./index.css";
import { Steps } from "antd";

const description = "This is a description.";
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Steps
      current={current}
      onChange={(num) => setCurrent(num)}
      items={[
        {
          title: "Finished",
          description
        },
        {
          title: "In Progress",
          description
        },
        {
          title: "Waiting",
          description
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default App;


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76849312/usage-of-steps-in-antd-v4-and-v5
```

Comment: Have you tried theming the `Stepper`? That way you could probably create your own `status` property with its own custom values

Comment: No @SebastianGbudje , can you please send me an example or any reference.

Comment: There's two things you could try
1) Theming the stepper [How to theme antd components](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme).
2) You could try doing some conditional rendering on the `status` property. like 
`status={current === 0 ? "Show some icon" : "show some other icon"}`. Since you're using TypeScript, you'll most likely have to theme since the `Step` component won't recognize non `String` values.

Comment: Spent sometime digging into this and your best bet would be to directly alter the CSS of the antd component you want changed. The Tick Icon is an SVG that's wrapped around a class. You'll need to change/override that.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianGbudje , I too had a look at it. Overwriting <span class="ant-steps-icon">1</span> or class related to it can work

Comment: i think you can use property "progressDot"

`progressDot={(iconDot, { index, status, title, description }) => {
        console.log(iconDot, index, status, title, description);
        return <></>;
      }}`

inside "progressDot" you can custom render of the all icon steps